# Sum Amount through the Ranges in SSRS Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!GLNUM.Value >= "KMBGL.2325" AND Fields!GLNUM.Value <="KMBGL.2875",Fields!AMOUNT.Value,0))
```

I am getting an error in the account field while using the above expression in the text field in the SSRS Report. 
Screenshot also been attached as an output.
[Error on the amount field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMqQT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because amount is decimal

Try this

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!GLNUM.Value >= "KMBGL.2325" AND Fields!GLNUM.Value <="KMBGL.2875",Fields!AMOUNT.Value,Cdec(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks alot the issue has been fixed now :)